# Не получается подобрать форматтер для вывода нужной строки по времени

Tags: java, kotlin

Мне нужно получить текущее время в виде строки в таком формате: `2019-12-24T09:20:35.8062135+03:00`. Никак не получается подобрать форматтер.

Проблема возникает с буквой Т посередине и форматом таймзоны. Вот такой вариант, например, не срабатывает и ругается на недопустимый символ Т посередине:

```
val FORMATTER: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSS Z")
println(ZonedDateTime.now().format(FORMATTER))
```

Comment: T возмите в одинарные кавычки. Т.е. `'T'`

Comment: @Chubatiy Спасибо! А что делать с таймзоной, не подскажите? Вот так отрезаются нули (которые мне нуны): `yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX`

Comment: `XXX` вместо `X`. И в итоге у вас получится нечто `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX`

Answer (score 0):

Такой формат родной для `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`
Создайте объект этого класса. Например так:
`xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gcal);`
gcal - объект класса java.util.GregorianCalendar
Дальше вызваем метод `toString`